# Is new, this, delete, typeof are javascript operators?

Tags: javascript

An interview question:

> Which of the following is not a JavaScript operator?
>
> `new, this, delete, typeof`

MDN lists them all as operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Special_operators).

I think the question is wrong, right?

Comment: My opinion would be that `this` is not an operator, obviously, but to answer those types of questions, [the actual specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) is often a much better source than MDN. The MDN is a good source for quick lookups of DOM-related stuff, not for the nitty-gritty details of JavaScript.

Comment: most likely yes.. although I believe `this` is a keyword technically

Comment: @Larabone Also, please remove the JSON and HTML tags.

Comment: What an awful interview question, as an aside.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Why? It tests whether the candidate has at least cursory knowledge of JS, imo. It's obvious that, of all those keywords, `this` is the only one that "needs nothing to operate on" and is therefore not an operator, but you can only know that if you know at least a little JS.

Comment: Well, MDN lists `this` as an operator, so there's at least a smidge of doubt around its classification. Being able to define exactly what an `operator` is is less interesting to me. If it gave the definition of operator, and then asked which of the following didn't fit the definition, that'd be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is not one of the ECMAScript operators. Like the other alphabetic operators it is a  [keyword](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1.1), but the [`this` keyword](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.1) directly builds a primary expression. I guess technically you could call it a "[nullary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity#Nullary) operator" :-)

That MDN categorized it under "operators" has often been critisized, but (AFAIK because of fearing dead links, and no better place available) no action has been taken yet.

Comment: It's probably best to note that, in this case (and since it's linked), the MDN docs are actually inaccurate by putting `this` on a list of operators on the linked page.

Comment: The list of keywords includes `instanceof`, `delete`, `new`, as well as `this`.