# What type is the 'return' keyword?

Tags: javascript, return, keyword

We use [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statements optionally in JavaScript functions. It's a keyword. But what is the actual type of `return` itself. Actually I got confused, seeing the example:

```
function add(a, b) {
  return (
    console.log(a + b),
    console.log(arguments)
  );
}

add(2, 2);
```

Output:

```
4
[2, 2]
```

So, we can pass comma separated expressions into the `return` statement. Is this a function?

And starting with this, can we take a wild guess that every keyword in JavaScript are ultimately a function?

I've written a small blog as a gist of this discussion. You may want to check it [here](http://coderuse.com/2016/04/JavaScript-What-is-the-type-of-return/).

Comment: Just when you thought you understood JavaScript, something like this turns up...

Comment: [The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: Brackets don't mean that you're calling function, for example: `var a = (2 + 2)`.

Comment: A more appropriate example is `var a = (1, 2)` -- this will result in `a` having the value `2` due to how the comma operator operates (yes, comma is a mathematical operator like `+` or `|` etc, specifically, in lambada calculus, the comma operator implements the K combinator)

Comment: in your example you're outputting a log to console (through the log method on the object console - callback) but you're returning undefined.

Comment: Then the correct action is to debunk the misconception, not downvote.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot [MDN docs on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) don't explicitly say what `this` is, but I guess it's most similar to a built-in constant, similarly to `undefined`.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka not really, this is standard behavior in any C-flavor language.

Comment: @Gothdo: Have a look at [Is `this` a javascript operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27001921/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi I know, but "a keyword" is a pretty broad expression.

Comment: The name for things like `this` is usually _pseudovariable_ if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot `return` is a [keyword](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-keywords), not a statement. But you can use it to form a [`return` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-return-statement).

Comment: @Oriol Ah, I misinterpreted the spec. So a `return` statement consists of the `return` keyword followed by an optional expression and a semicolon. That makes more sense.

Comment: I think what most answers fail to address (mine included) is the fundamental misunderstanding that return somehow allows a function to have an effect, that console.log doesn't need a return to make it work (and indeed this doesn't really make sense)

Comment: What is the type of `{` or `}` or `function` or `for` or `while` or `var`?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom not in the UK. () are brackets here.

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you. I was unaware. You and the venerable OED have enlightened me. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/bracket

Comment: @AlexanderMac it turns out that your use of the term "brackets" is quite correct everywhere except in the US. My apologies for being overly provincial.

Answer (score 128):

> But what is the actual type of 'return' itself.

It doesn't have a type, it isn't a value.

Attempting `typeof return;` will give you `Unexpected token return`.

> So, we can pass comma separated expressions into the return statement. Is this a function?

No, while parenthesis *can* be used to call a function, here they are a [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) containing a couple of expressions seperated by a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

A more useful demonstration would be:

```
function add(a, b) {
  return (
    (a + b),
    (a - b)
  );
}

console.log(add(2, 2));
```

Which outputs `0` because the result of `a + b` is ignored (it is on the LHS of the comma operator) and `a - b` is returned.

Comment: But, in the above example, each of the expressions are executed, one by one. I think the case you stated is different than what is stated in the original question. What I want to say is where is the precedence of Group operator is applied there.

Comment: @ArnabDas — Yes, they are executed, but `return` doesn't get to see them, which is what you were asking.

Comment: @ArnabDas — " What I want to say is where is the precedence of Group operator is applied there." — Within the grouping operator of course.

Comment: @ Quentin --- are you saying that, in your example also, each of the expressions, separated by comma are executed?

Comment: @ArnabDas — Yes. `a + b` just has no visible effect because it has no side effects and the value is discarded (well, given that it has no practical effect, it is possible that an optimising compiler might remove it, but that makes no practical difference).

Comment: To show it another way: `return (blah1, blah2);` is equivalent to `var temp = (blah1, blah2); return temp;`

Comment: @Barmar If I understand correctly, it is also equivalent to `blah1; return blah2;` is that right?

Comment: @Roman that's correct. The only way to "skip" an expression so that it is not executed (aside from within a conditional like `if`) is short circuit evaluation. The comma operator doesn't short circuit, so it'll evaluate both sides. Then it'll return the last one. That is explicitly the purpose of the comma operator, to group expressions in a single statement (usually the resulting value of the entire statement is ignored), most often used for variable initialization: `var i = 2, j = 3, k = 4;`

Comment: @Quentin May I suggest you include an additional snippet similar to the OP's and compare the two? I tried to unconsciously compare the two and got confused as to how the first one is returning two values and the second only one. Then I realized that in the OP's question we're not printing the returned value.

Comment: @cst1992 — The comparison is already there. I just didn't copy/paste the code from the question, because it is in the question.

Answer (score 32):

I'm kinda shocked that no one here has directly referenced [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9):

> 12.9 The return Statement Syntax ReturnStatement : return ; return [no LineTerminator here] Expression ;
>
> **Semantics**
>
> An ECMAScript program is considered syntactically incorrect if it
>   contains a return statement that is not within a FunctionBody. A
>   return statement causes a function to cease execution and return a
>   value to the caller. If Expression is omitted, the return value is
>   undefined. Otherwise, the return value is the value of Expression.
>
> A ReturnStatement is evaluated as follows:
>
> If the Expression is not present, return `(return, undefined, empty)`.
>   Let `exprRef` be the result of evaluating Expression.
>   Return `(return, GetValue(exprRef), empty)`.

So, because of the spec, your example reads:

`return ( GetValue(exprRef) )`

where
`exprRef = console.log(a + b), console.log(arguments)`

Which according to the [spec on the comma operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14)...

> **Semantics**
>
> The production Expression : Expression , AssignmentExpression is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> ```
> Let lref be the result of evaluating Expression.
> Call GetValue(lref).
> Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
> Return GetValue(rref).
> ```

...means that every expression will get evaluated until the last item in the comma list, which becomes the assignment expression.  So your code `return (console.log(a + b) , console.log(arguments))` is going to

1.)  print the result of `a + b`

2.)  Nothing is left to execute, so execute the next expression which

3.)  prints the `arguments`, and because `console.log()` doesn't specify a 
return statement

4.)  Evaluates to undefined

5.)  Which is then returned to the caller.

So the correct answer is, `return` doesn't have a type, it only returns the result of some expression.

For the next question:

> So, we can pass comma separated expressions into the return statement.
>   Is this a function?

No.  The comma in JavaScript is an operator, defined to allow you to combine multiple expressions into a single line, and is defined by the spec to return the evaluated expression of whatever is last in your list.

You still don't believe me?

```
<script>
alert(foo());
function foo(){
    var foo = undefined + undefined;
    console.log(foo);
    return undefined, console.log(1), 4;
}
</script>
```

Play with that code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LLpg025y/) and mess with the last value in the list.  It will always return the last value in the list, in your case it just happens to be `undefined.`

For your final question,

> And starting with this, can we take a wild guess that every keyword in
>   JavaScript are ultimately a function?

Again, no.  [Functions have a very specific definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) in the language.  I won't reprint it here because this answer is already getting extremely long.

Answer (score 15):

Testing what happens when you return parenthesiesed values:

```
function foo() {
    return (1, 2);
}

console.log(foo());
```

Gives the answer `2`, so it appears that a comma separated list of values evaluates to the last element in the list.

Really, the parenthesis are irrelevant here, they're grouping operations instead of signifying a function call. What's possibly surprising, though, is that the comma is legal here. I found an interesting blog post on how the comma is deal with here:

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

Comment: I guess then, something like `return ([1, 2])` should print both values?

Comment: That would be returning an array.

Comment: `console.log((1, 2))`

Answer (score 9):

`return` is not a function. It's the *continuation* of the function in which it occurs.

Think about the statement `alert (2 * foo(bar));` where `foo` is the name of a function. When you're evaluating it, you see that you have to set aside the rest of the statement for a moment to concentrate on evaluating `foo(bar)`. You could visualize the part you set aside as something like `alert (2 * _)`, with a blank to fill in. When you know what the value of `foo(bar)` is, you pick it up again.

The thing you set aside was the *continuation* of the call `foo(bar)`.

Calling `return` feeds a value to that continuation.

When you evaluate a *function* inside `foo`, the rest of `foo` waits for that function to reduce to a value, and then `foo` picks up again. You still have a goal to evaluate `foo(bar)`, it's just paused.

When you evaluate `return` inside `foo`, no part of `foo` waits around for a value. `return` doesn't reduce to a value at the place inside `foo` where you used it. Instead, it causes the entire *call* `foo(bar)` to reduce to a value, and the goal "evaluate `foo(bar)`" is deemed complete and blown away.

People don't usually tell you about continuations when you're new to programming. They think of it as an advanced topic, just because there *are* some very advanced things that people eventually *do* with continuations. But the truth is, you're using them all along, every time you call a function.

Comment: This sort of thinking is common with functional languages, like LISP and Haskell, but I've never seen it used in procedural languages like javascript.  One typically does not think of them as continuations because most procedural languages treat them as a special case.  For example, you can't save off the continuation of `alert(2 * _)` for later use in Javascript (there's a different notation to do that sort of thing).

Comment: @CortAmmon While I sort of agree with you, note that Javascript does have quite a strong functional background (it was originally intended as an implementation of a Scheme subset with a C-like syntax), and while it doesn't have any standard functions for manipulating continuations (e.g. call/cc) it *is* common practice to use continuation passing style in many javascript libraries, so understanding the concept at an early stage is quite useful for JS programmers.

Comment: It's true that Javascript doesn't do *first-class* continuations. The `return` from inside `foo` isn't a value; you couldn't pack it up in a data structure, assign it to a variable, wait a while and then feed something to it later -- and you especially couldn't feed it more than once. But, like I said, advanced topics.

Comment: Likewise, implementing a new control structure using continuations: advanced. But trying to implement a `my_if` function that behaves just like built-in `if()then{}else{}`, and failing to do so even if you allow yourself to use the built-in inside it -- not terribly advanced, and enormously instructive, especially if you're going to end up in code that passes around callbacks.

Answer (score 6):

the `return` here is a red herring. Perhaps interesting ist the following variation:

```
function add(a, b) {
  return (
    console.log(a + b),
    console.log(arguments)
  );
}

console.log(add(2, 2));
```

which outputs as the last line

```
undefined
```

as the function does not actually return anything. (It would return the return value of the second `console.log`, if it had one).

As it is, the code is exactly identical to

```
function add(a, b) {
    console.log(a + b);
    console.log(arguments);
}

console.log(add(2, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

An interesting way to understand the [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement is through the [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) operator
Take a look at this code

```js
var console = {
    log: function(s) {
      document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += s + "<br/>"
    }
}

function funReturnUndefined(x,y) {
   return ( void(x+y) );
}

function funReturnResult(x,y) {
   return ( (x+y) );
}

console.log( funReturnUndefined(2,3) );
console.log( funReturnResult(2,3) );
```

```html
<div id="console" />
```

Since the `return` statement takes one argument that is `[[expression]]` and return this to the caller on the stack i.e. `arguments.callee.caller` it will then execute `void(expression)` and then return `undefined` that is the evaluation of the void operator.